# Why do these autolayout constraints not resize this UILabel?

Tags: swift, autolayout

In my project I have a `UIScrollView` view pinned to the edges of the screen. Inside that is a `UIView` pinned to the edges of the `UIScrollView`. Inside the `UIView` I have a `UILabel` constrained to the `UIView` so that there are 20 pixels to the left, right, and top of the superview. The problem is that the although the left and top constraints work the right one does not as the label is not correctly resized. I fell like there is something I fundamently don't understand about how constraints work.

[my xcode console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEP7q.png)

Comment: you are missing one constraint on that label. also, Xcode doesn't always render the views in designtime, you should see a warning which will lead to a prompt to update the layout. but first of all, add the missing constraint

Comment: I added the final constraint however it doesn't seem to have done anything.